# How to display values while plotting on graph in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have read csv file using pandas, plotted using matplotlib and funcAnimate with delay of 100ms. Need to display value of each data when it plots.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd


plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animation(i):
  HV = pd.read_csv('FCW_HV.csv')
  lat_HV = []
  lon_HV = []
  lat_HV = HV[0:i]['Latitude(deg)']
  lon_HV = HV[0:i][' Longitude(deg)']
  ax.clear()
  plt.title('FCW Scenario')
  plt.xlabel('Longitude')
  plt.ylabel('Latitude')

  ax.scatter(lon_HV, lat_HV,s=30, marker="s",label='HV')
  plt.legend(loc='upper left');

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `Text` object that you update in your animation function, for example:

```
long, lat = lon_HV[-1], lat_HV[-1]
text = f"({long:.1f}°, {lat:.1f}°)" # Format this however you want.
ax.text(0.95, 0.95, text, transform=ax.transAxes) # This transform will force the text to 
                                                  # stay in the top-right bottom of your figure.
```

I would also advise that you move the line `HV = pd.read_csv('FCW_HV.csv')` outside of your animation since you only need to read the file once. The animation function only needs to slice that data.

The code is now:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
HV = pd.read_csv('FCW_HV.csv')
    
def animation(i):
    lat_HV = HV[0:i+1]['Latitude(deg)']
    lon_HV = HV[0:i+1][' Longitude(deg)']
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_title('FCW Scenario')
    ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
    ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

    long, lat = lon_HV[-1], lat_HV[-1]
    text = f"({long:.1f}°, {lat:.1f}°)"
    ax.text(0.95, 0.95, text, transform=ax.transAxes) 

    ax.scatter(lon_HV, lat_HV,s=30, marker="s",label='HV')
    ax.legend(loc='upper left');

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation, interval=100)
fig.show()
```

I have modified the indexes so that your slices are `[0:i+1]` otherwise the first frame does not contain any data and `long, lat = ...` fails and throws an IndexError.

Comment: animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation, interval=100)

fig.show() # modified figure as fig

No error but unable to see plot

Comment: @manojpai My bad, I wrote `figure` out of habit. Does it work nicely then?

Comment: I should use in fig.show() or plt.show() because I am not getting the plot